Como hacer que JPA nombre las tablas en mayúscula en spring boot
Estoy usando JPA con spring boot, hibernate y PostgreSQL, cuando intento colocar nombre de tablas que inician en mayúsculas al compilarlo los cambia a minúsculas ¿Cómo puedo hacer que reconozca el nombre de las tablas en mayúsculas?
Envía el siguiente error:
    2024-08-22T18:03:09.750-05:00  WARN 18056 --- [seguritycontrol] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2024-08-22T18:03:09.751-05:00 ERROR 18056 --- [seguritycontrol] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "xcontrol.municipios" does not exist
  Position: 58
2024-08-22T18:03:09.870-05:00 ERROR 18056 --- [seguritycontrol] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select m1_0.municipio,m1_0.departamento,m1_0.nombre from xcontrol."municipios" m1_0] [ERROR: relation "xcontrol.municipios" does not exist
  Position: 58] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "xcontrol.municipios" does not exist


This question is similar to: Hacer que JPA nombre las tablas en mayuscula. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Tuve el mismo problema, ya que el nombre de la tabla comenzaba en mayúscula y lo solucione así:
 @Table(name = "\"Municipios\"", schema = "schema")
public class Municipality {

y agregar esta linea en mi application.properties
 spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

Saludos.
